# t-sql loop through all rows and sum amount from column until value is reached

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing the below test data:

[image: A table with userId, Name, Email and Amount of persons a table in restaurant is reserved for]

I now would like to fill a restaurant with **12** seating spaces.

This should result in:

[image: table result after selection]

Basically, I need to loop from top to bottom through all rows and add the AmountPersons until I have filled the restaurant.

In this example:

(first few rows: AmountPersons) 3+1+2+4 = 10

UserId 52 can't be added because they reserved for 3 persons, which would result in 13 occupied places and there are only 12 available.

In the next row it notices a reservation for 1. This can be added to the previous 10 we already found.

NewTotal is now 11.

UserId 79 and 82 can't be added because we'd exceed the capacity again.

UserId 95 reserved for 1, this one can be added and we now have all places filled.

This is the result I get from the cursor I use, but I'm stuck now. Please help.

[image: Temp_Result_Cursor]

The while loop I have in the cursor basically stops when the next value would be higher than 12. But that is not correct.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: @GMB: Doesn't the title say t-sql

Comment: @Dieter . . . A title is not a tag.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit simple minded, but I'd populate a temp table as I process each row, skipping rows which would result in a sum > 12, and terminating the loop when the sum of the rows in the temp table equals 12.  I then have a reference (the temp table) with which to update or delete the rows in the source table (e.g. update a 'Seated' column to  TRUE).  I find simple approaches to perform better, and be more maintainable.

Comment: And how to determine the order of the rows? Shouldn't you collect first all the users with 1s, then 2s etc. until you reach the limit? Unclear task...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to skip rows, you need a recursive CTE.  But it is tricky -- because you may not have a group following your rules that adds up to exactly 12.

So:

```
with tn as (
         select t.*, row_number() over (order by userid) as seqnum
         from t
        ),
       cte as (
        select userId, name, amountPersons as total, 1 as is_included, seqnum
        from tn 
        where seqnum = 1
        union all
        select tn.userId, tn.name, 
               (case when tn.amountPersons + cte.total <= 12
                     then tn.amountPersons + cte.total
                     else cte.total
                end),
               (case when tn.amountPersons + cte.total <= 12
                     then 1
                     else 0
                end) as is_included,
               tn.seqnum
        from cte join
             tn
             on tn.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
        where cte.total < 12
    )
select cte.*
from cte
where is_included = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5cf6d79bf31388c8aea4ee652e7a3ad) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that if you change "I" to a larger value, then it is not included and the number of occupied seats is 11, not 12.

Comment: *order by userid* Why do you use ordering by `id`?

Comment: @JohnyL . . . I don't understand the comment.  There is no `order by id` in this answer and the db<>fiddle appears to work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not sure if this ok, but I have a follow-up question. How can I add an ORDER BY clause to the query in `with tn as ()`? I have this fifth column named Count_Invited, which increases every time they're invited. And when I could order the first select statement it would automatically return the persons who were least invited. `ORDER BY Count_Invited ASC` returns the error **The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.**

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nevermind, I just had to update the ORDER BY clause in the `row_number() over...` and use Count_Invited instead of userid.